# Can 't find mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to create a dedicated mongoose createConnection. Node.js rapports:

```
 MyModel = conn.model('Profile', profileSchema),
```

profileSchema is not defined.  But where did I go wrong?

```html
//my db.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const conn = mongoose.createConnection = ("mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase"),
    MyModel = conn.model('Profile', profileSchema),
    m = new MyModel;
m.save(); //works; 



if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    conn = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
}

require('./profiles)
```

Here the rest of my model page:

```html
// my profile.js

// JavaScript source code
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

   
    });

var MyModel = mongoose.model('Profile', profileSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your code, First learn how module works in javascript.
You need to export the **`profileSchema`** inorder to use inside the app.js, it should be,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },


    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', profileSchema);
```

then need to import profileSchema which lies inside profile depend on your file path.

```
const profileSchema = require('./model/profile.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is

```
// my profile.js

// JavaScript source code
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },


    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', profileSchema);
```

and in your app.js file put like this

```
const profileInfo= require('./../model/profile.js');
```